# kotlin-variable parameter error when inherit

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin

```
open class A(vararg vars: String)
class B(vararg vars: String):A(vars)
```

Error :

> Required:String
>   Found: Array

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Pass a string instead of an array. We can't help you unless you post more code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use spread operator for this

```
open class A(vararg vars: String)
class B(vararg vars: String):A(*vars)
```